# Run Time Error 1004 'Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable class'

Tags: vba, excel, range, runtime-error

I am trying to use the code to select all the rows under one of the subheaders in a pivot table.  I am getting a run time error 1004:

> Unable to get the PivotFields property of the Pivot Table class

From this code:

```
 Sub ttest()
 Dim pt As PivotTable
 Set pt = Sheets("Report").PivotTables("PivotTable1")

 pt.PivotFields("Row Labels").PivotItems("CL").DataRange.Select

 End Sub
```

Why?

Comment: that means the pivot field is not called 'Row Labels'

Comment: That did it... Stupid on my part I guess

Answer (score 8):

I may add an extra answer (as I found nothing on that):

For people working with **Data Model Pivot Tables**, field names are not obvious ([*tablename*].[*fieldname*].[*fieldname2*]).
Hence I suggest using following loop to understand what fields are currently in your pivot table:

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(ptName)

For Each pf In pt.PivotFields
    Debug.Print pf.Name
Next
```

This way you'll have all the names listed in the immediate view.

Comment: This is just what i was looking for!

Comment: The issue with this is the array is loaded with the table name, field name and the field when using data model pivot tables

Answer (score 5):

As JosieP said in the comments, the `1004` error means that there is no such `object`, that is there is no such `pivot field` that is called "Row Labels".