# How do I get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable Class?

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot

I am looking for a way to filter my PivotTable based on machine types (a field that I dragged to the filter box for my pivot table).

I have used the below formula before and it has worked, however, I am getting

> error 1004: unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable Class.

Cell A1 has the machine name that I am filtering for

```vb
Sub FilterbyMachine()

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Set pt = Sheets("Pivottables").PivotTables("MachineStats")

    Dim pf As PivotField
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Machine")

    pf.ClearAllFilters

    'slow iterates all items and sets Visible (manual filter)
    Dim pi As PivotItem
    For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
        pi.Visible = (pi.Name = Range("a1"))
    Next

    'fast way sets a label filter
    pf.PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=Range("a1")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Not that will help with your problem, but `pt.ManualUpdate = True` before the loop and then set to `False` will certainly improve the speed.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error on this line?:

```
 Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Machine")
```

I think it may be that there may not be a pivotField by that name. [Like here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429746/run-time-error-1004-unable-to-get-the-pivotfields-property-of-the-pivottable-cl)

Try adding this right before that line to check what names are there:

```
    For Each pf In pt.PivotFields
            Debug.Print (pf.Name)
    Next pf
```

Edit for additional options:
It may be related to the pivot cache. You could try calling the sub [from here](https://www.contextures.com/xlPivot11.html#refall) (below), in the same spot.

```
Sub RefreshAllPivotCaches()
' Developed by Contextures Inc.
' www.contextures.com
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim lPCs As Long
Dim lPC As Long
Dim lProb As Long

Set wb = Application.ThisWorkbook
lPCs = wb.PivotCaches.Count

For lPC = 1 To lPCs
  wb.PivotCaches(lPC).Refresh
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Could not refresh pivot cache " & lPC _
      & vbCrLf _
      & "Error: " _
      & vbCrLf _
      & Err.Description
    Err.Clear
    lProb = lProb + 1
  End If
Next lPC

MsgBox "Refresh is complete. " _
  & vbCrLf _
  & "Pivot Cache Count: " & lPCs _
  & vbCrLf _
  & "Failed refreshes: " & lProb

End Sub
```

It may not be necessary to keep it. Try running it once on its own. Then your code. If that's good you may want to put a call to this in error handling around the set pf line. In case it happens again. Something like this:

```
Setpf:
Dim CachesCleared as Boolean
On Error Goto ClearPivotCache
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Machine")
Goto FieldsAreGood ' no need to clear if it's working

ClearPivotCache:
On Error Goto 0 ' reset error handling
If not CachesCleared Then ' only try clearing once, no infinite loops
    Call RefreshAllPivotCaches
    CachesCleared = True
    Goto SetPF
Endif

FieldsAreGood:
On Error Goto 0 ' reset error handling
' The rest of your code
```

### If it does work out and you include it in some way, you will probably want to comment out, or swap for Debug.Prints, the MsgBoxes.

Comment: I added the above lines (copy and pasted) right in between the "Dim pf As PivotField" and the Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Machine")"  however I am still getting the error message for the Set pf line.  The Machine field is within my Pivot table (I can make it a column, filter, etc. - currently I have it under filters).

Answer (score 0):

For future generations,
a quick first thing to check is that macro is defined in the Excel sheet and not in a module.
I might be wrong but it solved my problem.