# Pivot table to refresh active workbook, select Item "Period", clear all selection and choose 2 last values

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, selection

After performing some operations this part of code goes to the sheet called "Overview", refreshes a huge pivot table - there is only one and it is called "PivotTable2" (actually, it doesn't refresh it and I don't know why). The part earlier that adds lines to the source works so after refreshing it manually everything works. Next, it chooses every cell with a value "Period" and what I need it to do is to clear filters in the selection "Period" and select two last values that pop up after the pivot table is refreshed.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Overview").Activate

Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField

For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
    pt.RefreshTable

Set pf = pt.PageFields("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Period")
    
    For Each pf In pt.PageFields
        pf.ClearManualFilter
        pf.ClearAllFilters
        pf.EnableMultiplePageItems = True
        pf.AutoSort xlAscending, pf.SourceName
        pf.CurrentPage = pf.PivotItems(pf.PivotItems.Count).Name
        If pf.CurrentPage = "(blank)" And pf.PivotItems.Count > 2 Then
            pf.CurrentPage = pf.PivotItems(pf.PivotItems.Count - 2).Name
        End If
        If pf.CurrentPage = "(blank)" And pf.PivotItems.Count > 1 Then
            pf.CurrentPage = pf.PivotItems(pf.PivotItems.Count - 1).Name
        End If
    Next pf
Next pt


End Sub
```

Run-time error '1004':

Unable to get the PageFields property of the PivotTable class

I would be happy if you point at a problem or suggest a solution. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, but there is still an error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429746/run-time-error-1004-unable-to-get-the-pivotfields-property-of-the-pivottable-cl.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is now with the line  `Set pf = pt.PageFields("Period")`, - Unable to get the PageFields property. BUT IT WORKS! ClearManualfilter doesn't though. I have more things selected than I needed

Answer (score 0):

This code works, but instead of only working with the field "Period" as my code suggests it performs operations on all fields in a pivot table and chooses 2 last values in a filter.

```
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField


For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
    pt.RefreshTable

Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Period")
    
        For Each pf In pt.PageFields
        pf.ClearManualFilter
        pf.ClearAllFilters
        pf.EnableMultiplePageItems = True
        pf.AutoSort xlAscending, pf.SourceName
        pf.CurrentPage = pf.PivotItems(pf.PivotItems.Count).Name
        If pf.CurrentPage = "(blank)" And pf.PivotItems.Count > 2 Then
            pf.CurrentPage = pf.PivotItems(pf.PivotItems.Count - 2).Name
        End If
        If pf.CurrentPage = "(blank)" And pf.PivotItems.Count > 1 Then
            pf.CurrentPage = pf.PivotItems(pf.PivotItems.Count - 1).Name
        End If
    Next pf
  Next pt
```